# where can I download whole debian 5 packages?I want to have all the repositries offline

Tags: debian

I want to download all debian 5's standard repositories but I haven't found yet which place I can locate for doing that.

where can I find a place to download those? 
I've heard that there 5 dvd other than the debian 5's dvd but I haven't found anything :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

http://www.debian.org/mirror/

Comment: it is mirror not the ISO files 
where can I find ISO images?
thanks anyway

Comment: It's listed on the page linked by me.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `apt-mirror` to make a local mirror of all the apt packages. I've done this a few times to download all the ubuntu repository to a harddrive when I was traveling to machines that didn't have good internet access.

Answer (score 0):

`Apt-Mirror` is fantastic for creating a local package repo. I did one for the `Testing` and `Stable` distributions back-in-the-day of Debian 3.

Also, consider the [jigdo-lite](http://www.debian.org/CD/jigdo-cd/#how) package. It can be used to produce up-to-date ISOs from *your* local repo. 
I would run apt-mirror every night with a `cron` job. Then I would have jigdo generate ISO's at the end of a week, and place them in my local web-server.  This mattered more for Testing than it did for stable.

Additionally, my package repo was also configured as a [netboot](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:EzyuGTkbSowJ:www.debian-administration.org/articles/478%20&cd=2&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=us&client=firefox-a) server.  Any of my local machines that could netboot, could be booted into the Debian installer over the network.

Consider the possibilities.

I haven't done this a very long time.